# Show that there is no set satisfying the following properties.

Tags: set-theory

Show that there is no set satisfying the following properties.

(a) If $X\in A$, then $\mathcal P(X)\in A$

(b) If $T\subseteq A$, then $\bigcup T\in A$

I wonder how to prove this problem.

According to the [note](http://karagila.org/files/set-theory-2017.pdf) that I saw this problem, this problem is called Hilbert's Paradox. But when I searched for Hilbert's paradox, I could only find something about the infinite-hotel. Is it related to this problem?

Comment: What is $P(x)$?

Comment: @G.Chiusole Probably $\mathcal P(x)$, the powerset.

Comment: @G.Chiusole Sorry. It is the powerset.

Comment: Note $A \subseteq A \Rightarrow \bigcup A \in A \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\cup A) \in A$. But, the last implication is impossible, I think. Not sure.

Comment: @amoogae No, Hilbert's hotel is not related to this paradox.

Comment: @freakish $A=\varnothing$ does not satisfy both conditions, since $\varnothing\subset\varnothing\to\varnothing\in A$.

Comment: @TheLastCipher Thank you. Your comment was very helpful.  I found a more direct proof. Since $A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\cup A) $ we get $A\in \mathcal{P} (\mathcal{P}(\cup A)) \in A$. And this is contradictory to axiom of regularity.

Comment: @amoogae I suggest you post your own argument as another answer (it is nice and short!), to increase its visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad to see my notes are in use. I should make the caveat that they were written for my students, who previously took introduction to set theory with Azriel Levy and myself (where *a lot* of material was covered).

---

Hilbert's paradox predates the axiom of regularity by quite a few years. So appealing to it in the solution is admittedly overshooting. The same can be said about replacement (which is used for transfinite recursion).

The solution, instead, is due to Zermelo, and it is quite clever: If $S$ satisfies the two properties, then $\bigcup S\in S$, and therefore $\mathcal P(\bigcup S)\in S$. This now implies that $\mathcal P(\bigcup S)\subseteq\bigcup S$. This is impossible, as the previous exercise in the notes points out, since $\{x\in X\mid x\notin x\}\in\mathcal P(X)\setminus X$ for any set $X$.

Of the "strong axioms", we only need separation and union, since power set is implicit in the properties of the set. Of the separation axioms, we only need one; and we only need union to apply to $S$ itself.

Comment: To give credit, I've learned on this problem and the solution from Kanamori's paper about Zermelo (I am a big believer in adding historical footnotes to the lectures). Kanamori, **Zermelo and set theory**, The Bulletin of Symbolic Logic 10(2004), 487-553.

Comment: Wow, I'm so happy to receive an answer from the author. In fact, your notes are difficult for me, but it helps a lot. And thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yes, I can see why, too. They were intended for my students that year who already had a lot of set theory basics drilled into them... As a guide, one star problems would be those that I would need to think about and look up, and two star problems are those that I know were solved but wouldn't be able to do myself. Not off the cuff anyway.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance. What are the "strong axioms" of set theory? Why are they called that? Is there a good reference you can point me to? I couldn't find "strong axioms" in the list of notes linked in the original problem.

Comment: @Andrew: It's an ad hoc term to describe, essentially, ZF without Extensionality. The point being that the other answer used Regularity and Replacement in quite an essential way, but that's not needed at all.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 2):

What you've stumbled upon is so called [von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe), at least partially.

Let $A_0:=\emptyset$. Note that since $\emptyset\subseteq A$ and $\bigcup\emptyset=\emptyset$ then $\emptyset\in A$ by  (b). Now for any ordinal $\alpha$ define

$$A_{\alpha+1}=P(A_\alpha)$$

and for a limit ordinal $\lambda$ define
$$A_{\lambda}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}A_\alpha$$

By the transfinite induction and (a)+(b) we get that $A_\alpha\in A$ for any ordinal $\alpha$. But these are pairwise distinct sets. Meaning $A$ is at least as big as all ordinals, and so it cannot be a set by [the Burali-Forti paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox).

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, now I don't know about ordinal numbers. After studying it, I will definitely read your answer. And I found a more direct proof. Since $A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\cup A) $ we get $A\in \mathcal{P} (\mathcal{P}(\cup A)) \in A$. And this is contradictory to axiom of regularity.

Comment: @amoogae Yes, and perhaps something like that is what Asaf had in mind so early in the notes. But the argument in this answer does not require the use of regularity.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Aha. Thank you for your important comment.

Comment: @Andrés: That was not what I had in mind, though.

Comment: @Asaf The "something like that" was there on purpose. :-)

Comment: Just to clarify, since the chapter about ordinals and recursion comes after this exercise, and long before the discussion about the von Neumann hierarchy, this is definitely not the intended solution. (Although the students were, in theory, at a position to make the inference regarding ordinals already at the end of their introductory course.)

Answer (score 2):

I proved this with a hint of TheLast Cipher's comment in the original post.

Note that $A \subseteq A \Rightarrow \bigcup A \in A \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\cup A) \in A \Rightarrow \mathcal{P} (\mathcal{P}(\cup A)) \in A$. Since $A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\cup A)$ we get $A\in P(P(∪A))\in A$. And this is contradictory to axiom of regularity.