# Can we characterize properties that don't make a set?

Tags: set-theory

Following to the ZFC system, there is no set that satisfies some kind of properties. For example, as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3405799/show-that-there-is-no-set-satisfying-the-following-properties) question. Can we characterize what that property is? Or at least we can make useful sufficient conditions? Or do we have a list of these kinds of properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\sf ZF(C)$ we have the von Neumann hierarchy, $V_\alpha$, which satisfies:

1. $V_\alpha$ is a set for every ordinal $\alpha$, and $V_\alpha\subseteq V_\beta$ for $\alpha\leq\beta$.
2. Every set $x$ lies in some $V_\alpha$.

Therefore, $\varphi(u)$ *does not define a set* if and only if for every $\alpha$, there is $x\notin V_\alpha$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds. In other words, $\varphi$ defines a set if and only if all sets satisfying $\varphi$ are in some $V_\alpha$.

Of course, we can easily engineer $\varphi$'s that in different models of set theory, or under different extensions of $\sf ZFC$, will define different sets, or even a proper class. For example $\varphi(u)$ is defined as $\lnot\sf CH$ will either be satisfied by none of the sets assuming $\sf CH$, in which case it defines the empty set, or all of them if $\sf CH$ fails, in which case it does not define a set.

But $\varphi$ *provably* defines a set if and only if we can *prove* that there is *some* bound (although we don't necessary need to be able to produce that bound). An example to that is $\varphi(u)$ states that $u$ is an ordinal, and $u$ can be injected into $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, this provably defines a set, but we cannot prove what is the least $\alpha$ which bounds all the members of that set.